# Font in use, in the LEGO BOOST adverts?

Tags: font-identification

I watched [this](https://www.facebook.com/LEGO/videos/10154337010463403/) video from Lego's facebook page advertising LEGO BOOST, I was curious about the font they used in the subtitle. I did a search as well as use a couple of reverse font searches, but to no avail. (what the font and identifont)

[image]

It looks like a mashup of Helvetica and adineue.

Can any one identify it or is it one of those made specifically for the ad campaign fonts?

Comment: The link to the image you added is broken, can you fix it? Also have you used any of the identification websites? We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: By reverse font search I meant font identification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chalet is a font family produced by [House Industries](https://houseind.com/hi/chalet). The typeface in question is most likely **Chalet New York 1960**:

[image]

That being said, after tracking down a [LEGO® Brand Identity & Experience PDF](http://www.hothbricks.com/pdf/6123880.pdf), I was able figure out that this font may have been renamed for internal purposes or modified to be a proprietary LEGO® typeface called **LEGO Chalet 60**:

[image]

This font is most likely protected by LEGO® for their exclusive use so if [Chalet New York 1960](https://houseind.com/hi/chalet) isn't an option, you might want to look into using a similar neo-grotesque style typeface. Here's a few alternatives that could work:

[Neue Haas Unica Pro Bold:](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-haas-unica/)

[image]

[Rational Semibold:](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rene-bieder/rational/)

[image]

[Acronym Bold:](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/acronym/)

[image]

Comment: above and beyond the call of duty!